# Can using Varnish still help to improve the performance of my site if I already use CloudFlare?

Tags: performance, proxy, cloudflare

I'm using CloudFlare right now. Can Varnish still help to improve the performance of my site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it could still help. Although CloudFlare caches [static content](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172516-What-file-extensions-does-CloudFlare-cache-for-static-content-), it doesn't cache [dynamic content served](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172826-Can-dynamic-sites-work-with-CloudFlare-) by your server, which could be of benefit as covered [here](http://www.anchor.com.au/hosting/dedicated/CreatingHighPerformanceDynamicWebSitesWithTheVarnishHttpAccelerator).

Some methods to use both in conjunction are covered [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169376-Can-I-use-benefits-with-CloudFlare-and-Varnish-) and [here](http://www.danielmiessler.com/blog/getting-real-ip-addresses-using-cloudflare-nginx-and-varnish).

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick correction:

CloudFlare won't cache dynamic content by default. You can, however, use [PageRules to cache dynamic content](http://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-pagerules-advanced-caching) (use with some care).